ColorScaling only to one axis on Discrete3dPlot?
I am trying to visualise a probability function in terms of number of trials/number of successes, and I'm using Discrete3DPlot to do so. I've figured out how to set up the graph so that colors go from red to green as the probability increases, but what I would like to do is have it so that for each row n, the color function shows the point with the highest probability on that row as the highest value, irrespective of whether values in other rows are higher.
The code I'm using (both for calculating the probability function and generating the Discrete3DPlot) is:
Multiset[n_Integer /; n >= 0, k_Integer /; k >= 0] :=  Binomial[n + k - 1, n - 1]

Multiset[n_Integer /; n >= 0, k_Integer /; k >= 0, r_Integer /; r >= 0] := 
    Sum[(-1)^i*Binomial[n, i]*Multiset[n, k - i*(r + 1)], {i, 0, Min[n, Floor[k/(1 + r)]]}]

RedtoGreen[z_] := RGBColor[1 - z, z, 0]

limix[d_Integer, e_Integer, t_Integer, b_Integer, r_Integer, n_Integer, h_Integer] := 
    Sum[Binomial[n, j]*Binomial[j*(r + 1), k]*Binomial[n - j, l]*
    Multiset[n - j, 2*i + Abs[h - j*(r + 1) + 2*k - l], r]*
    Binomial[2*i + Abs[h - j*(r + 1) + 2*k - l], i + Abs[h - j*(r + 1) + 2*k - l]]*
    ((d - e + 1)/d)^(j*(r + 1) - k + i + Max[0, h - j*(r + 1) + 2*k - l])*
    (b/d)^(k + i - Min[0, h - j*(r + 1) + 2*k - l])*
    ((e - t)/d)^l * ((t - b - 1) / d)^(n - j - l), 
    {j, 0, n}, {k, 0, j*(r + 1)}, {l, 0, n - j}, 
    {i, 0, Floor[(r*(n - j) - Abs[h - j*(r + 1) + 2*k - l])/2]}]

DiscretePlot3D[limix[10, 10, 7, 1, 3, n, h], {n, 1, 10}, {h, -20, 20}, ExtentSize -> Full, 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, If[z == 0, Black, RedtoGreen[z]]]]


This works to generate a Discrete3DPlot that scales everything to the highest point on the plot, but I'd rather have it scaled to the highest point for each n (so that the highest value on each row is better highlighted). Is there a way to do this? I don't want to have to include the function I'm plotting itself in the ColorFunction, because hoo boy the multiple summation takes quite a while at higher n, and I'd rather a more general solution anyway if there is one.
